# Class Method as Application Handler

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a method of my class as application handler for when the scene's frame is changed. For that I'm using `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)`. My approach is the same as described on the [Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) with the difference that my function is a method of my class:

```
import bpy
class MyClass(object):
    def my_handler(self, scene):
        print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
my_object = MyClass()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_object.my_handler)
```

However, I am getting this error message:

`TypeError: my_handler() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

When I do `my_object.my_handler(bpy.data.scenes[0])` I correctly get the frame number whenever I change the keyframe.

Where am I going wrong?

Why does the function get 3 arguments passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add the `depsgraph`.**

Since 2.8 most handlers take both a scene and a depsgraph argument, the latter is generally a kwarg.

If set up as a simple function this is fine

```
import bpy
# test clear
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()

def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

However if using a method of some instanced class, the way blender is wiring this up under the hood requires the extra argument defined for depsgraph. (*Even if it is always `None` in FCPre*)

Code below, same result as code above.

```
import bpy
# test clear
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()

class MyClass(object):
    def my_handler(self, scene, depsgraph):
        print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current, depsgraph)

my_object = MyClass()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_object.my_handler)
```